# TFS 2013 Team Explorer Extension : Release notes data

Tags: tfs, release-management, team-explorer

I have an extension to be able to generate release notes from TFS Team Explorer. That main feature is working and the document is generated based on selected queries available in the team's project.

But now I want to enable users to keep track of release notes entries so that for each release notes generated, I have a record available with all the data. Kind of like the build definitions, but then in a separate navigation item.

To do that, I would need to add "custom" data schema element to support storing the release notes data. How can I do that??

I have already thought about using a custom work item type, but I don't think that would be a nice fit. Adding custom tables, ... etc is not actually a nice thing either...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems there are two options here:

- Indeed adding a custom work item type
- Get to work with the Teamfoundation server side API

The latter is what I discovered the last 2 days. The following link is a starting point to understand how data is stored in TFS :
[Components of the TFS data warehouse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244687(v=vs.120).aspx)

There you can read all about the operational databases where we can add data. Then adapters can be written. The purpose of the warehouse adapter is to put the operational data into a form usable by the data warehouse.

So for a third party tool like what I want to do here, this seems the way to go.

Comment: It's worth noting that data warehouse adapters are basically undocumented. I tried to write one a few months ago and gave up in despair from lack of documentation and the overall opacity of the API.